# Conditional (true/false) inside mongdb query without specifiying column

Tags: mongodb

Let say I have a mongodb document

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John"
}
```

and I have a variable outside the database named `const x: string;`. 
how do I translate this conditional filtering like sql can do
`SELECT * FROM document WHERE x = "admin" AND id = 1` 
this query `{ "id": 1, x: "admin" }` doesnt work.

Comment: Does `x` refers to any field in DB ? If x = 'John' then it's 
like `{ "id": 1, name: x }`

Comment: no. `x` is not field in a document.

Comment: `x` should be a field inside document - It's basic functionality of any database, you can't do this